# Sphinx tutorial - problems

Tags: windows, python-sphinx

Following the Sphinx [sampledoc tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/sampledoc/) (written by the matplotlib authors) I run into problems customizing the look and feel.

The project builds with no errors, but instead of this

[image: tutorial screenshot]

I see this

[image: actual output wide]

or if I narrow the window, this

[image: actual output narrow]

(project name redacted by me).

I have tried turning on verbose output from `sphinx-build` but nothing hints at what might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial is for an older version of Sphinx, where the default theme has changed. You have to change the `html_theme` option in `conf.py` to `classic`, which is the old default.